# NodeJs read 6 digits OTP from yubikey

Tags: node.js, yubico

I have a nodejs script which I need to run periodically and it required me to input 6 digits OTP as a part of authentication process. That OTP is generated by hardware yubikey and I need to ope Yubico Authenticator every time I run the script. I was wondering if I can automate the reading process so the script would be able to get that password automatically or when it is inserted or when I touch the key.

I tried to see if I can assign it to one of the slots and it seems like it supports only yubico OTP and does not allow me to use what I have.

I also tried to find if there is a ready solution for that but all related libraries are working with either U2F or a different type of OTP.

PS I can't use other type of OTP, that's the only thing supported by AWS apart from gemalto.

PPS Maybe that 6 digits OTP got a name which I'm not aware of to improve my search results

Answer (score 0):

The YubiKey Manager CLI '[ykman otp calculate](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000012643-yubikey-manager-cli-ykman-user-manual#ykman_otp_calculate0vlni)' command can generate a TOTP code. Would that meet your need?

Feel free to [inspect the source code](https://github.com/Yubico/yubikey-manager) to learn how the command works under the covers.

Comment: It looks like in my case I need `ykman oath code` command, is there a simple way to read it via nodejs other than actually running shell command and parsing the output?